# next-auth using graphql apollo as data source

Tags: typescript, next.js, graphql, apollo-client, next-auth

Hi stackoverflow community,

I need some help pls,

I have a GraphQL data source, I'm using apollo client to pull those data.
I am currently working on my login function; I am using next-auth credential provider:
[Edited code below with the fetch call to graphql ]

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export default NextAuth({
    session: {
        strategy: 'jwt',
    },
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, user}: any) {
            if(user?._id) token._id = user._id;
            return token;
        },
        async session({ session, token}: any) {
            if(token?._id) session.user._id = token._id;
            return session;
        },
    },
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            async authorize(credentials: any) {
                const query = `query User($email: String!) { user(email: $email) { id, username, email, password, }}`;
                const response: any = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/graphql', {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json","Accept": "application/json", },
                    body: JSON.stringify({query, variables: { email: credentials.email }})
                });
                const {data}: any = await response.json();
                if(data) {
                    return {
                        _id: data.user.id,
                        name: data.user.username,
                        email: data.user.email,
                    };
                } 
                throw new Error("Invalid email or password");
            },
        }),
    ],
});
```

Here's my getUser hook
[ Commenting this out since this is no longer relevant

```
// import { useQuery, gql } from '@apollo/client';

// const Get_User = gql`
// query User($email: String!) {
//   user(email: $email) {
//     id
//     username
//     email
//     password
//   }
// }
// `;


// export default function getUser(email: any) {
//     const { error,  data } = useQuery(Get_User, {variables: {email}});

//     return {
//         error,
//         data,
//     }
// }
```

I've verified that my next-auth endpoint is working by commenting out the GraphQL getUser and changing the if statement comparing to itself (credential.password === credential.password) and returning a statically written data back.

data inside credentials object is passing and accessing the values correctly.

[YES I WAS :( ] I think I am violating some react hooks law here, but I can't quite figure out how to address this, any enlightenment would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance! ^-^

So now it seems like theres something wrong with my fetch timings as it won't return my user details as expected even though my fetch request is working if tested on another page.

Comment: So I figured what I was doing wrong, as  mentioned by @michel I'm not using `useQuery` in an actual react component, so what I did was I created a fetch call to the graphql api, I tested the fetch call in a separate page it works! but it doesnt work inside nextauth which is weird, I'll edit my question for details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yeh to summarize all a stupid mistake and wrong understanding of how the technology I'm using is supposed to do, I thought I could just execute `useQuery` from apollo library as a next-auth providers that lead to me violating react's hook policy, what I should've done was to fetch to graphql directly either by using another library like `axios` or simply the `fetch api` here's my final code

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export default NextAuth({
session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
},
callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user}) {
        if(user?._id) token._id = user._id;
        return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token}) {
        if(token?._id) session.user._id = token._id;
        return session;
    },
},
providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
        async authorize(credentials) {
            const query = `query Users {
                users {
                  id
                  username
                  email
                  password
                }
              }`;

            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/graphql', {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({query})
            });
            const { data } = await response.json();
            const user = await data.users.find((dat) => dat.email === credentials.email);
            if(user && user.password === credentials.password) {
                return {
                    _id: user._id,
                    name: user.username,
                    email: user.email,
                };
            } 
            throw new Error("Invalid email or password");
        },
    }),
],
});
```

so yeh, I wasn't sure if this what @michel meant so I'll just put this as my answer instead. cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You're using a hook inside a function that's not a React component, i.e. your `GetUser` function is returning an object instead of other components. Plus `useQuery` is asynchronous so that function will not actually return data.

You can use `client.query` in a function where `client` is your Apollo client object. Or you can use `useQuery` inside an actual react component.